# Greek text copy & paste fails

Tags: greek, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste some text from a greek pdf file that I created in latex using texstudio, but the pasted text appears messed up. Here is an example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
% \usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc} USING THIS OR NOT MAKES NO DIFFERENCE
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\title{Εξισορρόπηση διπλού ανάστροφου εκκρεμούς}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The printed pdf looks fine, yet when I try to copy and paste the text, it appears like this:

Exisorrìphsh diploÔ anstrofou ekkre mo Ôc

or even like this

❊①✐s♦rrì♣❤s❤ ❞✐♣❧♦Ô ❛♥❼str♦❢♦✉ ❡❦❦r❡♠♦Ô❝

Is there any choice in Latex that can change this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `utf8x` and also add the bits I show below; then also Adobe Reader seems to be happy.

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\title{Εξισορρόπηση διπλού ανάστροφου εκκρεμούς}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. using utf8 produces a lot of errors.

Comment: @LazarosMoysis Update your TeX distribution

Comment: Thanks. I updated the inputenc package though and it still does not work with utf8.

Comment: @LazarosMoysis There's much more to update, I guess; what TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Miktex 2.9, and texstudio (I believe I have its latest version).

Comment: I systematically updated my miktex distribution and now it works. Thank you very much, I am accepting this as an answer!

Answer (score 6):

This could be an issue with your pdf viewer. For me, copy-paste works fine with your MWE (compiled with `pdflatex`) when viewed in Evince, but with Acrobat Reader I get the behaviour you describe.

Both viewers work on my machine when I use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, which allows you to explicitly define a font. MWE below, note that a Linux font is used here (change to, for example, `DejaVuSans` in Windows).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\title{Εξισορρόπηση διπλού ανάστροφου εκκρεμούς}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this does not work well. I try both xelatex and lualatex and change the font to times new roman, but the text appears with a lot of mistakes and errors. Inside the text (not used in the minimum working example) I use both greek and english and use commands like \textgreek{} and \textlatin{} etc